# Retrieve env.host id in Fabric2

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to port my code from Fabric 1.x to Fabric2.

In the old version of Fabric I used the `env.host` as an id for each machine:
`party_id = env.hosts.index(env.host)`

How can I do this in Fabric2?

===========UPDATE===========

I'm creating my hosts using this code snippet:

```
host_list = open('public_ips', 'r').read().splitlines()
        self.connections = []
        self.pool = Group()
        for host in host_list:
            self.pool.append(Connection(host, user='user', connect_kwargs={
                'key_filename': ['mykey.pem']
            }))
```

At runtime I need to know what is the index of each `Connection` object in the `ThreadingPool` object.

Comment: Its known bug in fabric 2.0, refer: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1869

Answer (score 0):

The `env.host` does not work with Fabric2, I faced the exact same issue when i discovered `Connection` object with `Fabric2`. With `Fabric2` you can access the host with `connection` object.

Here is a sample code

```
>>> import fabric
>>> res = fabric.ThreadingGroup('test1', 'test2').run('uptime')
 04:14:04 up 1 day, 16:20,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
 04:14:05 up 2 days,  1:55,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
>>> res
{<Connection host=test1>: <Result cmd='uptime' exited=0>, <Connection host=test2>: <Result cmd='uptime' exited=0>}
>>> for i in res:
...     print(i.host)
... 
test1
test2
```

Here is the link for information on [Fabric2 Connection](http://www.fabfile.org/#how-is-it-used)

Comment: You can't really do that with `Fabric2` but you can possibly incorporate every use case that you might want to do by using `env.host` at run time. The result object returned by `SerialGroup` and `ThreadingGroup` in `fabric2` contains the exit status as well for the hosts, so if you want to know something like which hosts run the command successfully you can get that with result object.Also you have to understand that `fabric2` works in a very different way than `fabric1` so porting coding from `fabric1` to `fabric2` involves using `fabric2` design, i've been through this exact situation.